# Write request and response data to file in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have one testcase which contains 7 requests. I need to write both request (whole request which is passing along with dynamic values) and response data (whole response) to a file for all of them during run time. Please help me how can I do this in JMeter?

Comment: You will turn your entire file system into a drag anchor for your performance test. This will slow all of the virtual users on your host, as file system actions are ring 0 for the operating system whereas applications (virtual users) are ring 3.  Your virtual users will have to wait for disk actions to complete.  This will introduce delays and your application response will track as slower than actual.  This action is ill advised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flexible file writer in the request. Give |requestData| and |responseData|
in "Record each sample as" field. Give the path where you want to save your data in Filename field. That's it.You will be able to see a file which contains the request and response data for the sampler request.Hope this helps!